# Why NaN inside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
        var Paint = (function(cells) {

        var step = $('.workplace').width()/cells;
        var plants = [];

        var cell = function(cells) {
            for (var i=1; i < cells; i++) {
            $('.workplace').append("<div class='line-vertical' style='left: " + step * i + "px;' >")
            $('.workplace').append("<div class='line-horizontal' style='top: " + step *i + "px;'>");
            }
    return {
      cell:cell
    }
        };)()

Paint.cell(10);
```

In this code step = NaN, why and how can I fixed it?

Comment: What is `cells`?  What is the result of `$('.workplace').width()`?  Try something like:  `console.log("width: " + $(".workplace").width() + " cells: " + cells);` and tell us what the console outputs in your browser.

Comment: You'll have to figure it out yourself, not enough details here.  First, what is the return value of `$('.workplace')` --- and then what is `$('.workplace').width()` and lastly what is the value of `cells`.  Something here is Not a Number, hence `NaN`

Comment: you are not passing any value to `cells` so it is undefined.... so `$('.workplace').width()/cells` will result in `NaN`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I call like this "Paint.cell(10);" and its NaN

Comment: @user2971752 It is not the inner function (`Paint.cell`) which has the missing parameter, it is the outer function (starting with `(function(cells) {` and ending `};)()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example of your code that highlights the problem...

```
var Paint = (function(cells) {
    alert(cells);
})();
```

It would work if you defined the cells argument...

```
var Paint = (function(cells) {
    alert(cells);
})(5);
```

Although I suspect you want to do that inside of the `cell` function, so move your width calculation inside there.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function which takes a single parameter (`function(cells)`), but you are then immediately executing it without any parameters; if we take the first and last lines of your code, you get this:

```
var Paint = (function(cells) {
     // code referencing cells here
};)()
```

This assigns `Paint` not to the function, but to the result of *executing* that function, just as if you'd written this:

```
function something(cells) {
     // code referencing cells here
};
var Paint = something()
```

Since you are executing the function with no parameters, `cells` will be undefined, so the line which is erroring:

```
var step = $('.workplace').width()/cells;
```

is dividing a number by an undefined variable.